# Cannot find module '@tanstack/react-table' despite it being installed

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a TypeScript React project and I'm trying to import ColumnDef from @tanstack/react-table in my columns.tsx file.

```
import { ColumnDef } from "@tanstack/react-table";

export type Payment = {
  id: string;
  amount: number;
  status: "pending" | "processing" | "success" | "failed";
  email: string;
};

export const columns: ColumnDef<Payment>[] = [
  {
    accessorKey: "status",
    header: "Status",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "email",
    header: "Email",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "amount",
    header: "Amount",
  },
];
```

However, I'm getting the following TypeScript error:

```
Cannot find module '@tanstack/react-table' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

I've already installed @tanstack/react-table using npm. I've also tried doing the --save-dev as well as deleting my node_modules folder and package-lock.json file, then running npm install again, but the error persists.

Any ideas on what could be causing this and how to fix it or what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem today, but with React Query. I tried the same things you did to no avail.

What ended up working was restarting the Typescript server. Like this...

- **For Windows in VS Code:** Press **Ctrl + Shift + P** and select **>TypeScript: Restart TS server.**
- **For macOS in VS Code:** Press ⇧ + ⌘ + P or F1 and select **>TypeScript: Restart TS server**.

Let me know if this worked. If not, we'll try to get it figured out.

As a last resort, if you need to bypass the TypeScript error temporarily, you can use *// @ts-expect-error* above the import path. However, this is not recommended as a long-term solution since it ignores type checking:

```
import { 
    ColumnDef 
    // @ts-expect-error descr must go here
} from "@tanstack/react-table";
```